# Manual refresh button for SP2010 Web Part

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, refresh

I'm a novice SharePoint user. I have been given a task to build a manual refresh button for a  web part that displays certain fields from a list. The native refresh button is not a feasible option for me as it is not available in the datasheet view and that is used most by average users. Automatic data refresh also won't work because of network and bandwidth restrictions.
I would really appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Do keep it really simple, you could add a picture of a button and add a hyperlink to the button that points to the same site that you are currently in. Simple, easy and no code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I really am a novice.... could you elaborate on your answer a bit? specifically how to get the link for refreshing the web part and how to add the image?

Comment: Are you using a custom webpart or an out of the box webpart?

Comment: An out of the box webpart.

Comment: Ah, and what webparts? Content Query web part?

Comment: That or the list view one, not sure between the two.

Answer (score 0):

@Christoffer, you saved me a lot of time. 
Adding a refresh icon and set Hyperlink to the same page. 
Brilliant. 
Thank you.